# Level spacing statistics of the quantum Ising model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, statistics

Consider the quantum Ising model defined by the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
    \hat H=-\sum_j\hat\sigma_j^z \hat\sigma_{j+1}^z-h\sum_j \hat\sigma_j^x-g\sum_j\hat\sigma_j^z.
\end{equation}
For $g=0$, we expect the system to be integrable due to the symmetry of spin inversion with respect to the $x$-axis, and therefore the level spacing statistics (that is, the gaps between the normalized eigenvalues of $\hat H$) should follow an exponential, Poisson-like distribution.

For $g\ne 0$, the symmetry is broken and the system should be no longer integrable. Therefore, in this case the level spacing statistics is given by the Wigner-Dyson distribution $p_\gamma(x)\sim s^\gamma e^{-x^2}$.

In my numerical implementation (using standard values of the parameters such as $N=10$ for the number of spins, $h=2$ and $g=0.5$ for the field strengths) I find however that the level spacing statistics is Poissonian even with a nonzero longitudinal field, which is definitely unexpected (and almost surely wrong). Assuming the correctness of the code (which works reasonably in all other cases), is there anything that might explain this incongruent behaviour?

Comment: Don’t you rather mean when $h=0$? In this case you look at the $\sigma^z$ simultaneous eigenbasis and the Hamiltonian is diagonalizable explicitly for all $g$. It’s usually as you vary $h$ that things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Often, when Wigner-Dyson level statistics are expected but not observed in the numerics, it is because there is an unresolved symmetry.

If the Hamiltonian is, for example, translation invariant or is invariant under a reflection around the centre-point of your spin chain, then you need to restrict to the spectrum to the symmetry subspace. Maybe this is what is going wrong?

The python QuSpin package might help you to resolve symmetries in your Hamiltonian if this is the issue (https://github.com/QuSpin/QuSpin).